# Jump over a bottle?

Tags: lateral-thinking, humor

A friend of mine challenged me to jump over a bottle on the floor. I'm good at jumping over obstacles so I accepted. But then I realized that I couldn't do it!
**Why? Explain!**

*Notes: I'm not injured. The floor isn't sticky or irregular. The bottle has standard size of 1,5L. Jumping means that you "take off" from the floor, pass above the bottle without touching it, then land on the floor*

Comment: Downvoter please explain your action. If it's because the text isn't clear, just ask and I'll explain.

Comment: @leoll2  I did not dv nor will i vote to close.  As you are relatively new but very active though I just wanted to caution you about the "speculative answers" close reason.  There was a time when this question would have been closed reflexively. http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/why-are-questions-off-topic-if-they-invite-answers-which-are-not-demonstrably-co?s=1|0.6180

Comment: You're trapped in the Matrix and you realize the truth... there is no bottle.

Comment: @kaine Good point! Personally, I think that my question admits no more than few correct and logical answers, if people answer stupidly (eg breaking physics law or nonsense) I won't support those answers

Comment: @leoll2 I agree but some of the questions that inspired that close reason allowed fewer than this.  The complaint was that the motivation for which "correct" answer to select was based on bias OP preference. If I wanted this question closed, I would vote to close it.  But for your own sake see: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/568/getting-the-100-dollar-bill-under-the-inverted-pyramid

Comment: @kaine Good example. In order to circumscribe the problem and make the problem less "broad",  I tried to add several notes, but apparently it wasn't enough. I'll discuss about lateral-thinking in meta asap, as I really believe that the lateral-thinking policy can be improved, for the good of the whole community.

Comment: leoll2 lateral thinking could surely be improved (or removed) the problem with the tag is it opens up for many different 'correct' answers since it invites answers such as daniel, cubicorn and Mark N's ansewrs. though A.D. and @kaine are the only intuitive and "logical" answer to why one might not be able to jump over it. A trend i've seen with lateral thinking is it often incites answers based on humoring the reader. (Cubicon) while I don't mind and am happy to upvote such an answer. it might not be the intent of p.SE and I will gladly respond on meta if i can.

Comment: There's a single answer that works, and it's not a trick question. I'm annoyed I'm not allowed to answer because a few other people didn't "get" it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think

> he put the bottle on the floor against the wall in the corner of the room

Comment: So you go onto the next floor or onto the roof of the building and jump over it there.  (Though this is most likely the intended answer.)

Comment: @kaine but is it really jumping over?

Comment: @kaine, they could be on a roof. But then I don't think they would really be your 'friend'

Comment: You jump and pass over the bottle.  It is as fair as his placement of the bottle.  The truth is we don't know enough of the situation to say for sure what happened. The comment is just fun.

Comment: In order to beat your friend, however, you put  a small table over the bottle and jump up and down on that. You are now "jumping over the bottle" using a linguistic trick similar to "biting an inch off a poker" :-)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution (there are several) is that

> he put the bottle underneath a large table or other piece of furniture.

Note there are lateral thinking ways to get around some of the obsticales presented by this idea such as jumping on the furniture in such a way that you go over the bottle while remaining on the furniture.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is that the bottle is

> on a floor that you can't get to, like a bottle on the floor of a secure facility you don't have access to.

Another possibility is that the

> ceiling is too low for you to jump over the bottle.

More generally these all mean there is

> some sort of obstruction preventing you from jumping over the bottle.

Comment: Good attempt, but the floor is the same for you, your friend and the bottle

Comment: @leoll2 Your comment doesn't make any sense to me. In what way is the floor different for you, your friend, or the bottle in either of his scenarios? You can easily be on the same floor and still be separated by a locked door. Or are you trying to say that you must be in the same room?

Answer (score 3):

A more unlikely situation:

> Your friend lives in a rotating house where they ceiling can become the floor (after being rotating around). He glues the bottle onto the ceiling (which can also be a floor but currently isn't). Then he read what A.D. said, and glues it into the corner of the ceiling.

Answer (score 3):

A solution you should not tell to [black hat](https://xkcd.com/169/):

> When he challenged you to "jump over a bottle on the floor", he meant "on the floor" to refer to you and not the bottle.  You can't technically be "on the floor" and jump at the same time, and so...hey...put that machete down!!!